# Error in Ubuntu Dual Boot Partitions: import_mok_state failed

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, grub, gnu

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 as dual boot  along Windows 10 following this  [tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) using a USB. But   after restart Ubuntu wouldn't load. I tried this 4 times. Then, I deleted the dual booted partitions via Disk Management Software
[image]

Now after startup, i get this as first screen:
[image: startup]
[image: Details of each partition]
I can still proceed to windows after entering exit but sometimes I get this error:
***Something has seriously gone wrong. import_mok_state failed.***
I didn't get the error after restart

How can I completely delete the GPT partitions so I stop getting this error?

Comment: Check if there is a Windows Boot Manager UEFI entry still present in your BIOS. If this is the case, make it the default entry and test if Windows works as expected. You can remove the leftover Ubuntu boot entry, the remaining partition (disk management shows 3 partitions, but GRUB lists 4 partitions?) and files in your ESP later from a live USB.

Comment: Windows updates may also update UEFI firmware. Which generally is a good thing, but it resets many settings to defaults. So you have to go back and redo any settings you changed. Anything related to MOK - machine owner key is UEFI Secure Boot Related. Many turn off Secure boot at least for now.